# mysql boolean mode select query

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

When I run the following query on the records in table:

```
SELECT TRIM(city_table.City_Name)
   as label,city_table.Area_Name, city_table.Area_Code, city_table.City_Code as `City`,
   city_table.Country_Code ,city_table.Country_Name as CountryName,
   city_table.City_Code as `value`
FROM `city_table`
where MATCH(city_table.SearchString) AGAINST('+al* +ain*' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

no data is returned. and I can see that I have "al ain" but when I run same query:

```
SELECT TRIM(city_table.City_Name)
   as label,city_table.Area_Name, city_table.Area_Code, city_table.City_Code as `City`,
   city_table.Country_Code ,city_table.Country_Name as CountryName, city_table.City_Code as `value`
FROM `city_table`
where MATCH(city_table.SearchString)
AGAINST('+dub*' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

records are returned correctly.

Similarly, records are not returned for:

```
SELECT TRIM(city_table.City_Name)
   as label,city_table.Area_Name, city_table.Area_Code, city_table.City_Code as `City`,city_table.Country_Code ,
   city_table.Country_Name as CountryName, city_table.City_Code as `value`
FROM `city_table` where MATCH(city_table.SearchString)
AGAINST('+umm*' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

But the same query with different string like 'Gha' or 'Ajm' will return records.

The table has the records for 'umm' and 'al' but are still not showing it. I am unable to attach the image of the record to show but I have the following fields in table.

City_Name  City_Code  Area_Name ￼  Area_Code  Country_Code SearchString Country_Name .

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything glaringly incorrect, however, it's possible, and you should be aware, that by default, the minimum value for length of word to be indexed in FULLTEXT index is four characters.  Sometimes it will work, other times not!  See [Potentially relevant info here.](http://www.tipandtrick.net/how-to-change-mysql-fulltext-index-minimum-and-maximum-length-of-words/)

Comment: i change it my.cnf file to ft_min_word_len=1 but it is still not showing. strange thing is SELECT TRIM(city_table.City_Name) as label,city_table.Area_Name, city_table.Area_Code, city_table.City_Code as `City`,city_table.Country_Code ,city_table.Country_Name as CountryName, city_table.City_Code as `value` FROM `city_table` where MATCH(city_table.SearchString) AGAINST('+The* +Palm*' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) order by city_table.priority desc limit 0,30 this query is not working. its more than 3 characters

Comment: Is the city name string in one column entry like "The Palm" ?